# Stitching Together a Picture in HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I'm in the process of developing a web app, and as part of it, I need to be able to manipulate pieces of a picture, specifically, the keys on a trumpet. I have each piece carved out from photoshop but I don't know how to align each key with the trumpet in a responsive manner: I can use absolute positioning to position the key but when the trumpet element resizes the keys no longer line up. Any tips?

Comment: have you thought about using an image map?

Comment: you could try using % instead of pixels to align them

Comment: @Jhecht might look into that

Answer (score 0):

Set the trumpet images to percentage widths, and wrap them with a container div with `min-width` and `max-width` properties so that they shrink and grow and content adjusts accordingly.

Comment: The problem isn't that the elements don't shrink or grow, it's that they don't stay precisely aligned where they should be on the trumpet so they look displaced

Comment: @AustinSerio without looking at the code we can't really say much. Are you by any chance using ``display: inline-block`` on the images?

Comment: No I'm not. Here's the code: 

position: absolute;
left: 54.3%;
width: 3%;
top: 50px;

The problem is that as the trumpet image shrinks, the point which the key needs to be aligned with effectively moves as the image shrinks while the key stays in the same place. Perhaps there is a better way to do this? I thought of potentially using a table.

Comment: Please update your question with the entire code, including the html markup you have right now. A fiddle would be ideal.

Comment: Here's the URL if that's alright? Otherwise I'll make the fiddle http://donaldtrumpet.austinserio.com (it's a gag web app, definitely not in support of him)